# Delphi XE7 TdateTimePicker missing weekdays on Windows 10 when style other than Windows

Tags: windows-10, vcl-styles, tdatetimepicker

What can cause this weird behaviour? Calendar does not show Monday and Sunday when style is other than Windows.

Delphi XE7 + Windows 10 (polish version tested).

[image: Missing monday and sunday on drop-down window]

Comment: try the 10.1 Berlin Trial and look if this also occurs. if not it was a VCL bug which was fixed in  a newer version

Comment: Try using the [VCL Styles Utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) project.